# Colombeau Algebra for physics students

Tags: resource-recommendations, dirac-delta-distributions

I have an undergraduate degree in physics, taken 2 years of calculus, and a rigorous course in linear algebra. I have not taken a math course in analysis, though have read a bit about it on my own.

There are books on distribution theory and generalized functions that are “friendly” to someone with my background (e.g. M. J. Lighthill, D. Jones). Is there something on [Colombeau Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombeau_algebra) that might also be friendly, to someone with my background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend "Multiplication of Distributions: A tool in mathematics, numerical engineering and theoretical physics" by J. F. Colombeau, the founder of this theory.

In this book, Colombeau presents his theory in an accessible way, free from mathematical techniques/definitions. The only background needed is familiarity with partial derivatives and integrations.

Comment: @Saleh_964 Thank You!